# Fast methods to consolidate 20 csv files into one xml file

Tags: design, c#, performance

We have 2 systems Legacy & New and I have to migrate the data from the legacy system to the new system.

The legacy system exports the data in .csv format while the new system accepts the data in XML format. I've built a converter to read the data from the CSV files and consolidate them into XML.

[image]

Some of the CSV files are hundreds of thousands while others are tiny. The issue is that converting 1k only takes about 4.5 minutes, converting 2k take about 9 minutes .. and so on.

The converter was built as:

1. creating all necessary objects; which means reading all CSV files and
   creating lists & dictionaries. initialization takes about 2 minutes.
2. **Start looping through each item in the "Main" CSV file. For each item in the "Main" CSV file, I'll have to lookup for some related data in other CSV files. Some of the "other" CSV files are thousands or hundreds of thousands**
3. Building the XML object. After finishing the loop, I serialize the XML object into an XML string and then save it to a file.

Step 2 is the one that'll take a very long time to complete and here is my question:
If you've faced such a scenario what would you do? How would you process such problem in a time-efficient way?

lastly:

- I've used [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) to read the files
- My system is: ASUS Vivobook M7600QE

Comment: In step 2, when you write *"I'll have to lookup for some related data in other CSV files"*, do you mean that literally, or do you lookup the related data in those dictionaries created in step 1 (from those CSV files)?

Comment: @Doc Brown, of course I mean in the lists & dictionaries created in step 1.

Comment: Then there is nothing you can do except detailed profiling step 2. Your problem isn't solvable without reviewing and profiling your code (and there is even no guarantee there exists a significantly faster solution for this hardware and software platform).

Comment: Is the lookup the slow part?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a "convert file format" project,
as the XML output files are not 1:1 saying what the CSV inputs say.
Rather, it is an
[ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) project.

Either the large "other" CSV tables fit in your Vivobook's memory,
or they don't. So we need an internal or external store for those records.
And it must be performant.
You are apparently doing sequential scans of external CSV tables now,
and finding that it doesn't go quickly.
Scanning or merging sorted copies of CSVs can make some problems
go quicker, but you've not revealed enough details to see if that's relevant.

If you can malloc() an internal hashmap for those CSV lookup records, then do so.
Otherwise, export rows to an external database, perhaps sqlite, and use indexed
[JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) for your lookups.

Comment: All CSVs fit in the memory (step 1) and the current processing is mostly sequential. great tip of exporting the data into a DBMS and joining them. Roughly how much percentage will the performance enhance?

Comment: @MaherNabil: you did not read this answer properly. When you can do all the processing in-memory, and do all the lookups using dictionaries, using an external storage system like a DBMS, even a lightweight solution like sqlite, will be much slower. What we definitely cannot tell you from the 100.000 feet view is if your implementation does all lookups efficiently, or if there is a "performance bug" in your code.